# HDD turning off despite power settings

Tags: hard-drive, power-management

I recently bought an SSD and installed Windows 7 Ultimate on it. Now I am using it and despite setting the power options to "Never" turn off hard disks one of my old HDDs is turning off when not used.

I have made sure I accessed the advanced settings of the power plan that I have chosen to be the active one.

This hasn't happened before.

Environmental changes:

- New SSD added.

- Windows installed on new SSD.

- The primary Windows installation used has been changed to the one on the SSD.

Answer (score 0):

What is the make of the "old" HDD - is it an energy efficient one such as WD Green? That *might* be something to do with it.

Something else to look at, I posted a question yesterday about PUIS - Power Up In Standby - again if your drive has this or similar, and the jumpers are set, it might be invoved? A longshot maybe?

I believe that many Enterprise/Server grade HDDs will automatically power down - I was looking at some WD Reds for this reason also.

Not a complete answer but hopefully will lead you in the right direction?

Just had a thought - do you mean spinning down or are the heads parking only?
There is this for the WD Green drives: to control the parking issue.
http://forums.ncix.com/forums/?mode=showthread&msg_id=2278208&threadid=2278208&forum=103&product_id=49591&msgcount=39&overclockid=0#msg2278208

Comment: Thanks! The old HDD is not energy efficient, green, red or any other color. :) That drive's jumpers aren't set for anything like that but I will double-check. It's consumer grade, so nothing like Enterprise/Server auto power downs. It didn't do that before I installed the "new" Windows.

Comment: When you installed the new SSD - did you change anything, like was your old windows setup a legacy BIOS mbr and then you installed the new windows to UEFI/GPT? Was it a clean install or upgrade / system clone?

Did you check your BIOS settings to see if there are any power settings? possibly if you changed from legacy to UEFI there could be a new setting showing up or functioning now, & if your data drive is still legacy mbr - it might be affecting it differently now?

Definitely worth checking the BIOS/UEFI - and if needed maybe update it to latest firmware version.

Comment: No, I didn't change anything. But looking in the BIOS might work, I'll have to do that in the next maintenance window.